# \includegraphics clipping and trim is squishing image

Tags: graphics, crop

Clipping keeps squishing my image.

My command is:

```
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=false,clip=true,trim=90px 0 0 0]{blue.jpg}
```

But I'm getting:

[image]

Where the original image is:

[image: unclipped]

Why can't I clip or trim an image *without* squishing?  There is a part of an image that I want to *cut off* without having to go into a photo editor to do it.

Comment: Does [the top answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57418/crop-an-inserted-image) help at all?

Comment: If you don't want that the image is distorted, why do you set `keepaspectratio` to false?

Comment: Because aspect ratio refers to width/height.  The aspect ratio of the clipped image will be smaller since I reduced the width.

Comment: Clipping should work, but @Ulrike is right, `keepaspectratio` is not needed here and should not be used. Also note that the `px` unit is a `pdftex` extension and uses a fixed (but configurable) density which might not be correct for this particular JPG. Sometimes the images metadata are not fully correct, leading to a wrong display with LaTeX.

Comment: Well imho the key should either be not necessary or have the value true. But why do you use the key at all? Do you set the width and height key globally?

Comment: Well actually, the `keepaspectratio` key has no effect.

Answer (score 11):

It is clearly a bug in the driver for package `graphicx`:

- `pdftex.def`: ok.
- `dvips.def`: ok for PostScript images, but clipping is not supported for bitmap images.
- `xetex.def`: Clipping is not supported at all.
- `dvipdfm.def`: The image is not trimmed, but distorted in the final area.
- `dvipdfmx.def`: The whole image is put in the final area without distortion, but
  empty space is put above the small image.

A remark to `keepaspectratio`: It has a meaning only if both the `width` and
`height` are specified. Thus the setting and values of `keepaspectratio` does not matter here.

There is a solution for `dvips.def`, `dvipdfm.def` and `dvipdfmx.def` if `pdfTeX` is used as TeX compiler (for DVI mode). Package `bmpsize` fixes as side effect the
defective drivers. And the package improves the bitmap inclusion making separate bounding box files obsolete. The driver `xetex.def` cannot be fixed this way, because XeTeX misses
primitives from pdfTeX (especially `\pdffiledump`), needed by `bmpsize`.

```
\usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx}
\usepackage{bmpsize}
```

Comment: Is there any way these issues can be fixed in the drivers themselves? For example, it's possible to do clipping for XeTeX not at the engine level but using the `xdvipdfmx` driver. [This also reminds me that I guess I should write some LaTeX3 driver code for picture importing :-)]

Comment: Clipping can be done via page operators or form xobjects. Someone has written clipping support for xetex.def and posted it to comp.text.tex, but I do not know the current state. The drivers seems not to be actively maintained.

Comment: 'Someone' in the context of `xetex.def` would be me, with some prodding from Martin Scharrer :-) I was under the impression that you were in charge of the driver code, hence asking. Obviously I was mistaken.

Comment: I am maintaining pdftex.def. Could you contact the maintainers of xetex.def?