# How to add pdf photo to LaTex?

Tags: pdf

I have created a diagram using word drawing, however, when I saved it as a pdf and exported it with LaTeX the figure seem to be the whole page and could not adjust it only the figure size. If anyone knows the solution, please help advice me. I tried to convert from pdf to esp file using Inkscape, but the figure was not clear although it looks fine as pdf.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show the code you're using for adding the picture?

Comment: This the code that I used   \includegraphics[height=0.4\textheight,angle=0]{filename.pdf}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done the following for including .pdf images in the past...

If I want to include an existing .pdf document:

```
\includepdf[offset=30mm -20mm,noautoscale,pages=1-2]{name_of_your.pdf}
```

If I want to include an image, like what you're doing:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \setlength\fboxrule{0.5pt}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{name_of_your.pdf}}
    \caption{lorem ipsum.}
    \label{fig:name_of}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! I don't think this answers the OPs question, I'm afraid. The problem is that when saving a PDF from Word, there is a lot of whitespace around the figure, and the OP wants to remove that whitespace.

Comment: Do you know how to get rid of this problem (the whitespace)  @TorbjørnT.

Comment: @sifo I thought that was your original question. The best way I know of is the one Alan mentioned in his answer. Another way is to use `trim` and `clip` as seen in for example [Crop an inserted image?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57418)

Comment: I think @gbby wrongly interpreted the question because the wording is ambiguous. "...the figure seem to be the whole page" could mean "the whole page of the LaTeX document," and that is how I interpreted it. I'm not a Word user, so I didn't know that "the PDF contains the whole page of the Word document" is what the OP meant.

Answer (score 6):

If you save an image created in Word, using Save As PDF, it will save a one page document with the image.  To turn this document into an image of the right size, you can use the `pdfcrop` program, which is part of TeX Live (and I assume MikTeX).  From the commandline, navigate to your file's folder and then use:

```
pdfcrop <your-pdf-file.pdf>
```

This will create a file named `<your-pdf-file-crop.pdf>`

This file can then be inserted into your TeX document using `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Or you can use the `trim` option of the `\includegraphics` command, which lets you crop the original pdf.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen The `pdfcrop` method is much simpler since you don't have to do any measuring of how much to trim. `pdfcrop` crops to the natural size of the content automatically.

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely try the command the next time I need a similar job.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Alan, but I did not really catch what you meant. Do you mean saving the file using different extension or just adding the code of pdfcrop instead of the one that I am using which is [\includegraphics {file.pdf}

Comment: @sifo No, you still use `\includegraphics` to insert your file, but you create a cropped version of the original file beforehand using the `pdfcrop` program.  You use that program from the command line. It's not part of your TeX document.  What OS and TeX distribution are you using?