# How can I remove unwanted white background in an .eps file?

Tags: eps, epstool

I want to crop an eps file which has a white background. Also, the figure is not produced with LATEX.
[image]

it is better to change:

[image]

Also, the link of eps file as,
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfiftqmov2cgq26/Fig2a.eps?dl=0

Comment: How exactly did you create the eps? If you are running the latex+dvips route, then you get a full page figure unless you use the `-E` option to `dvips`. Other than that you can either edit the bounding box manually (the EPS is just a text file, the bounding box is `x lower left y lower left x upper right y upper right`. Or convert it into PDF via `epstopdf` and use `pdfcrop` on it.

Comment: Thank you, the figure is made out of latex framework tools ( now, it is presented in MS word).

Comment: Ohh, misread your question then then. What exactly is your question and how is it related to LaTeX if it is Word you are using or am I misreading your text again?

Comment: My question is that there is a way which can crop the picture by Latex?  such as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57418/crop-an-inserted-image

Comment: Hi, little check: You did not scan the image, pasted it to a word document and exported it to eps (because eps has better quality)? A student of mine once did that and complained about the wide margins ;-)

Comment: Are you using it in LaTeX? Try opening the `eps` in your LaTeX editor (as mentioned it is just a text file). Then Replace the BoundingBox line by `%%BoundingBox: 200 630 390 750` (found by changing it by hand an previeiwing the result).  BTW: the methods in the link you provided also work in EPS files.

Comment: Ìt can be done with the excellent tool `epspdf` (a tex-lua script). I've done it , and obtained both a cropped .eps and the resulting .pdf. Is there any place where I can upload them?

Comment: There is a small utility called [`epstool`](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/epstool.htm) which can fix the bounding box.  Invoke it with `epstool --copy --bbox Fig2a.eps Fig2b.eps` at a command prompt.