# Convert small figure in .vsdx to .eps or use .pdf figure in latex

Tags: pdftex, epslatex

I have a small figure in visio and want to use it in LaTex file. I tried couple ways.

1. I copy it into `metafile2eps` and tried to convert directly. But the problem was that some of pictures (downloaded from internet) was not properly pasted and converted. So I gave up it!
2. I converted visio file into `.pdf` and then use following code:

   ```
   \begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\figwidth]{fig.pdf}
   \caption{system.}
   \label{f_system}
   \end{figure}
   ```

Actually, the pdf figure was good but the problem was that the pdf paper size is A4. However figure is small which occupies only 20% of page.

I cannot draw that figure fit into A4 or anyother standard paper size!

What would be the correct way to insert that small figure with size fit only into visio figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward solution is to crop the PDF file to the correct size, using an application such as Inkscape (free software) or Illustrator (commercial).

Alternatively, you can crop the image from within LaTeX, as explained in this answer 
[Crop an inserted image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57418/crop-an-inserted-image)

Comment: Both ways worked. I used Inkscape to convert crop pdf figure into .eps form. Thanks @Eric !