# Green border around PDF figure?

Tags: pdf, includegraphics

I'm doing a LaTeX beamer and am having a problem with \includegraphics. Around the image, a thin, green border is shown, which won't disappear in the presentation. This problem (or feature?) only occurs with one specific image and only when included as the original PDF (I want to keep the PDF to avoid loss in quality). I first thought, the problem stems from the package hyperref, so I tried to remove meta data, but nothing did change whatsoever.

[image: The image with the green border around it.]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=7.8cm, width=9.4cm]{Pictures/Stevie}
        \label{fig:Stevie}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Since the error only exists when using this one specific PDF, I provide the source image here: https://1drv.ms/b/s!An_8vYlVpuen3l5rtIgFKbYlZCDR

Comment: You could use `\includegraphics[..., trim=<trim params>,clip]{steve_jobs}` where `clip` specifies the lengths you want to remove from the left/bottom/right/top. See [Crop an inserted image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57418/5764)

Comment: Is the image in question available somewhere online? Having a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) would still be good as this would make it easier to test possible solutions for you.

Comment: Your NOT using hyperref in your preamble that we cant see are you ?

Comment: @KJO I am using hyperref but as can be seen with the MWE I added in the question, the problem remains also without the package. I had that thought too, that's why I removed the meta data of the PDF.

Comment: @samcarter I updated the post, please find the MWE imbedded.

Comment: @Werner It appears to be a border created by LaTeX, since it remains, also if I crop the main image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem to actually be in the PDF. There was a green background in the PDF itself, which was displayed when inserted in LaTeX. I managed to remove it with Adobe Acrobat.