# Simultaneously trimming and resizing an image with graphicx

Tags: graphics, errors, texstudio

I wonder, but couldn't find an existing answer to that.

So I want to crop an image and then resize it to fit the page width.
I get two errors `Missing number, treated as zero. {img.png}` and `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). {img.png}` (both referring to line y).
Output seems to be okay (also cropped and resized).

At first, I thought it was because of line x, because of that, it is split up like that over 3 lines. It works when I comment out before the word "trim", but I need that. Line x was double checked against different sources but I couldn't find an error.

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
%...
\begin{figure}[h]
    %   h (here) - same location
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=(0pt 30pt 0pt 0pt),% line x
    clip=true,width=\linewidth]
    {img.png} % line y, Error reported to be here
\end{figure}
```

To the comment: You're probably right and it is more obvious to do resizing and cropping seperately. But it is well defined: (Quoting [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer) from [Crop an inserted image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57426/110394))

> Note that all scaling/resizing is applied **after** the trimming. If you want the original image **be scaled** to 5cm width **and then** 50% **clipped**, just resize the clipped half to a width of 2.5cm **afterwards**

Comment: Personally, I always separate the two to make sure they are done in the right order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, one can use parentheses, but use curly brackets <kbd>{</kbd> and  <kbd>}</kbd>, not round ones  <kbd>(</kbd> and <kbd>)</kbd> (look closely), that mistake happened to me.

Correct code:

```
\usepackage{graphicx} %Thanks frougon for the tip with [pdftex]
%...
\begin{figure}[h]
    %   h (here) - same location
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim={0pt 30pt 0pt 0pt},% line x
    clip=true,width=\linewidth]
    {img.png} % line y, Error reported to be here
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Correct syntax:

```latex
\includegraphics[trim=0pt 30pt 0pt 0pt,...]{example-image}
```

(no parentheses after `trim=`; note that the unit is `bp` if you don't write any).

2) I would suggest not specifying the driver yourself to `graphicx`, as autodetection works fine as far as I can tell, you risk making a suboptimal choice, and may forget to update it if you later decide to recompile the document with a different engine.

Good:

```latex
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

“Bad”:

```latex
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
```

Full example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[trim=0pt 30pt 0pt 0pt,clip=true,width=\linewidth]%
                  {example-image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```