# Can you control existing margins (inherent within the image file) of an image in LaTeX?

Tags: margins

I inherited a lot of plots loaded into a LaTeX file. These plots are saved in .eps files with a lot of white margin on the top and bottom of the plot. 
I would prefer not to have to manually go into all these figures and crop out all the white space.

Is it possible to remove (partially) the top and bottom margins of the image files using LaTeX?

Comment: You do not have to do that manually, there are tools for that. You may just convert them to ps and back to eps and that may do the trick, there are better tools available, which depend a bit on the platform. But yes, `\includegraphics` has the option `trim`, yet I would really just crop the files automatically.

Comment: Duplicate of [Crop an inserted image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57418/crop-an-inserted-image) Did you even bother searching?