# How can I include Databricks notebook cell output (HTML) in my LaTex report?

Tags: tables, code, html, import, cell

I have the following output cell in an Databricks notebook (here as picture):

[image]

I would like to include this output in my LaTex report including the scroll bar. This should work through exporting the cell as an HTML. Here the code:

```
<iframe style="width:100%;border-width:0px;height:385px" srcdoc="<html><head><meta charset='utf-8'><meta name='google' content='notranslate'><meta http-equiv='Content-Language' content='en'><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/static/35484a53fa55bd4ce898c8c9527852c26f561da8afb2e31d8e238f43868ef325/lib/css/source_code_pro.css'><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/static/35484a53fa55bd4ce898c8c9527852c26f561da8afb2e31d8e238f43868ef325/lib/css/bootstrap.min.css'><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/static/35484a53fa55bd4ce898c8c9527852c26f561da8afb2e31d8e238f43868ef325/css/main.css'><meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF8'></head><body><div id='databricks-notebook-cell'></div><script>window.settings = {staticNotebookResourceUrl: 'https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/static/35484a53fa55bd4ce898c8c9527852c26f561da8afb2e31d8e238f43868ef325/', deploymentMode: 'production'};const notebookModelJson = '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';const notebookModelCommandCollection = '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';</script><script src='https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/static/35484a53fa55bd4ce898c8c9527852c26f561da8afb2e31d8e238f43868ef325/js/metrics-graphics.js'></script><script src='https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/static/35484a53fa55bd4ce898c8c9527852c26f561da8afb2e31d8e238f43868ef325/js/cell-main.js'></script></body></html>"></iframe>
```

How can I integrate this html code in my report ? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to download the data as a csv file and then recreate the table in LaTeX using this file (for example with the [`datatool`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool) package)?

Comment: Otherwise, you can print the notebook to PDF in the browser (just the page that has the table) and then include only the table part of that page in your LaTeX document (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57418/crop-an-inserted-image).