# How to increase the size of this figure?

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, subfloats, overleaf

I'm making a figure with four graphs next to each other but I want the graphs to be larger (without changing position). I don't mind giving up some of the margin for this, but how do you do this in latex? I have tried a couple of things but then the figure is not centered anymore.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
 \begin{center}\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{Figures/fundvsprice.pdf}\end{center}
  \vspace{-0.45cm}
  \subcaption{Fundamental versus real values}\label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
\begin{center}\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{Figures/fundvsprice.pdf}\end{center}
  \vspace{-0.45cm}
  \subcaption{Fundamental versus real values}\label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}%
\\
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
 \begin{center}\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{Figures/fundvsprice.pdf}\end{center}
  \vspace{-0.45cm}
  \subcaption{Fundamental versus real values}\label{fig:1c}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
\begin{center}\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{Figures/fundvsprice.pdf}\end{center}
  \vspace{-0.45cm}
  \subcaption{Fundamental versus real values}\label{fig:1d}
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{General caption.} \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct I see that these are MATLAB figures? In that case use '[tightfig](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34055-tightfig-hfig)' in MATLAB, that removes all the margins to start with. (I do not have enough rep to comment this :P)

otherwise you can use [Crop an inserted image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57418/crop-an-inserted-image)