# Crop image using relative offsets

Tags: graphics, crop

As of [Crop an inserted image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57418/crop-an-inserted-image) we can crop images by using something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
% trim from left edge
\includegraphics[trim={5cm 0 0 0},clip]{myImage.pdf}
\end{document}
```

in order to crop away the left 5cm of our example image.

In my example it would be really neat if I could use relative crop directions instead of absolute ones (e.g. crop a way 10% from the left, 25% from the top, etc.). Is this possible? And if so: how?

Unfortunately the documentation of the `graphicx` package is not very verbose when it comes to the `trim` option (at least as far as I have found).

In case it's relevant: I am looking for an option that works with PDF files included as images.

---

Note that I found https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57426/128658 that explains how the effect can be achieved by using a savebox to query the image's dimension first. I am hoping for a solution where this is automated in the background so I don't have to do this every time...

Comment: You can use `\adjincludegraphics` from [`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox), as suggested in the [linked answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57420/5764).

Comment: Oh my bad. Thanks for pointing this out!