# Include the text from a pdf

Tags: includegraphics

I want to include the text from another pdf. The first thing that came to my mind is to just use `\includegraphics[]{abc.pdf}`. However, the problem is that the pdf file consists of only one a4 page and has just a few lines of text and the rest of the page is empty. Thinking that I only have the text there and continue right after the text, I tried to type something but realized that it leaves the rest of the page I am on blank and continues the next page. How do I extract just the text with its format from that pdf and keep on writing right from the point the extracted text ends?

Comment: Use a scanner (or a smartphone...) to make a copy of the text you need. Or insert all the page scanned \includegraphics[scale=.7]{abc.pdf}.

Comment: I need the text with its format, though.

Comment: Have you considered running `pdfcrop "abc.pdf"` to trim off the empty space? You can also "trim" the image with the `trim=` option for `\includegraphics` (see e.g., [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57418/crop-an-inserted-image)), but I find it easier to have pdfcrop figure out what to crop for me.

Comment: Wow. I didn't know about ``pdfcrop``. That was what I was looking for. You can write it as a short answer about it if you like and I can mark it. Thank you!