# Why is the picture on the overleaf with low resolution?

Tags: diagrams

I created my original picture in Microsoft Visio. I save this picture in .png format. However, when I upload this picture to overleaf. The resolution of the picture decreases. I heard that I could upload in .pdf format. But for the pdf format, there is always some blank space on one page of the pdf. The code is listed below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \smashoperator macro

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{Taskinformation50.png}
\caption{Information about Task 50}
\label{fig:Task50}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Please find the picture here
https://ibb.co/s2wSkW1

Comment: the png will be included at the original  resolution but you are scaling it

Comment: As for the PDF being too large (how do you make the PNG into a PDF?). LaTeX come with the `pdfcrop` tool, that can remove whitespace from PDF files. Can Visio only do bibmaps? Would be better to save it as verctor graphics.

Comment: Or if you can't or don't want to use additional tools then you can also crop the Visio pdf while it is being included, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57418/crop-an-inserted-image.