# Why can't I scale my image?

Tags: graphics, scaling

I'm using the `graphics` package and I can insert my graphic into the document without any difficulty, apart from the fact that it's huge!

I am using the following command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphics}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{figure}[b]

  \centering

  \includegraphics{cinema}

  \caption{Fig. 1: Simple Past}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But when I insert the scaling option: `[scale=0.75]` etc. It won't work and I get the message

```
 Runaway argument?
scale=0.75]{cinema} \caption {Fig. 1: Simple Past} \end {figure} 
! Paragraph ended before \Gin@iii was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

Comment: @percusse and thanks for that, it's fixed now

Comment: Great added the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`graphicx`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/graphicx) package instead of [`graphics`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/graphics), as only the former supports the key-value syntax. For the `graphics` version, one needs to use

```
\scalebox{0.75}{\includegraphics{cinema}}
```

See eg [Packages: graphics vs graphicx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23076) and detailed [guide on graphics with LaTeX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/epslatex/english/epslatex.pdf).