# xinclude pdf in a latex document as appendix - where pdfpages does not work

Tags: pdf, appendices, pdfpages

I am having a problem including pdf pages in latex as appendix. I have tried using pdfpages but including \usepackage{pdfpages} in my style file of my thesis does not allow the code to work.  Below is a list of all the packages I am using.

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for improved inclusion of graphics
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % for better header layout
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt} 
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} 
\usepackage{nextpage}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[titletoc, title, toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

I have tried to use `\usepackage[draft]{pdfpages}` and `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}` but I still get an error. What is the thing I am doing wrongly?

```
Error: 
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphicx.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.146     \pdfcompresslevel
                           =9
?
```

Comment: `graphics` is deprecated, use `graphicx` instead http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23076/32374. What error are you getting exactly? Can you copy-paste into your question? Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: And also use provide a full minimal example and not just your preamble. We cannot see which document class you are using. It is also a good exercise to make a new copy of your document, and then start removing packages and recompile until you end up with something truely minimal. Often this process will end up with you finding the error your self.

Comment: Given the error, most likely whatever `documentclass` you use already loads `graphicx`. You really need to tell give us a full minimal example, as daleif said.

Comment: @daleif I agree recompiling could allow me to figure out the error, but somehow the graphicx package and pdfpages package go not go together. I have tried searching for an answer for this but it does not seem clear why they do not go together.      \documentclass[twoside,11pt]{style/ESSthesis}

Comment: You are missing the package `kitchen-sink`. :-(

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Option clash for package graphicx

means you have already loaded the graphicx package with other options. 
If you use `pdfpages`, you don't have to load `graphicx` by yourself, as it gets loaded by the package.

Comment: It's a little weird that commenting out one package manages to fix everything.. However it was not in the above text where I commented it out but in another section in my style document..