# Inserting an Image in Latex - Basics

Tags: graphics

It is my very very first time using LaTeX and I only need this program for preparing a homework which must include some graphics. For that I've been reading what to do for inserting an image but still not being able to add one, I seek for any kind of help. Would be very nice if you can explain this problem below and give me an advice.

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \usepackage
```

What I typed is this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\usepackage{graphics}

\includegraphics[scale=1]{ad.png} 
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `\usepackage{...}` has to go before `\begin{document}` (the part which is known as the preamble).

Comment: @hooy seems like an answer:-)

Comment: @Sel Did my answer solve your problem? If so, would you mind [accepting it](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1853/30280)?

Answer (score 9):

Loading packages with `\usepackage{...}` has to be done in the preamble, in other words before issuing `\begin{document}`.

So your code should be

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
% Load packages here  
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document} % Document content begins here

\includegraphics[scale=1]{ad.png}

\end{document}
```

Also, see [Packages: graphics vs graphicx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23075/30280) as to why you should use the [`graphicx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) (*x* for e**x**tended) package rather than the [`graphics`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphics) package.