# Where can I find the list of the example images of graphicx?

Tags: graphics, documentation

The `graphicx` package has many example images, but where are they listed?

I can't find this feature in the [package documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image}

\includegraphics{example-image-a}

\includegraphics{example-image-b}

\includegraphics{example-image-c}

\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related: [New support package for MWEs](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/5764)

Comment: @Werner Thank you! I thought it was a `graphicx` feature, they were include in the TeX distribution, instead!

Comment: As these files are in the TeX search path, their location can be found with, e. g., `kpsewhich example-image-duck.pdf`. The directory where these files are located usually equals the package name.

Comment: **there are no ducks in the graphicx package distribution** (but there is a cat)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've just realized that! Indeed, it seemed very strange to me :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX for the next release I may add a `hawaiian-pizza .png` example file in your honour.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh no!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are not provided by the `graphicx` package but by the `mwe` package (look into the `tex/latex/mwe/` folder of your TeX distribution.

`example-image-duck` on the other hand is provided by `duckuments`. As far as I know there is no comprehensive list showing all example images by packages.

---

File list for TeX Live 2018 (example files provided by `mwe`):

```
./example-image-golden-upright.pdf
./example-grid-100x100bp.tex
./example-image-a3-landscape.tex
./example-grid-100x100pt.jpg
./example-grid-100x100bp.eps
./example-image-16x9.jpg
./example-image-letter-landscape.tex
./example-image-1x1.jpg
./example-image-16x9.eps
./example-grid-100x100pt.png
./example-image-a4-numbered.tex
./example-image-4x3.pdf
./example-movie.pdf
./example-image-10x16.jpg
./example-image-1x1.eps
./example-image-a.tex
./example-image-golden.tex
./example-image-letter.tex
./example-grid-100x100pt.tex
./example-image-4x3.tex
./example-image-golden.pdf
./example-image-empty.pdf
./example-movie.mp4
./example-image-9x16.jpg
./example-image-a4-landscape.pdf
./example-image-a.png
./example-image-16x10.jpg
./example-image-10x16.png
./example-image-b.eps
./example-image-4x3.eps
./example-grid-100x100bp.pdf
./example-image-a4.tex
./example-image-a4.pdf
./example-image-16x10.png
./example-image-letter-landscape.pdf
./example-image-10x16.pdf
./example-image-c.pdf
./example-image-letter-numbered.tex
./example-image-letter.pdf
./example-image-4x3.png
./example-image.png
./example-image.jpg
./example-image-plain.pdf
./example-image-a.jpg
./example-image-1x1.png
./example-image-16x10.tex
./example-grid-100x100bp.jpg
./example-image-b.pdf
./example-image-c.jpg
./example-image-4x3.jpg
./example-image-a4-landscape.tex
./example-grid-100x100pt.eps
./example-image-a5-landscape.tex
./example-image-9x16.tex
./example-image-c.png
./example-image-a4-numbered.pdf
./example-image.pdf
./example-movie.tex
./example-image-1x1.tex
./example-image-9x16.png
./example-image-16x10.pdf
./example-image-16x9.png
./example-image-c.tex
./example-image-b.jpg
./example-image-a.pdf
./example-image.tex
./example-image-a5.pdf
./example-grid-100x100pt.pdf
./example-image-1x1.pdf
./example-image-golden-upright.tex
./example-image-b.tex
./example-image-a3-landscape.pdf
./example-image-a3.pdf
./example-image-b.png
./example-image-9x16.pdf
./example-image-16x9.tex
./example-image-empty.tex
./example-image-a5-landscape.pdf
./example-grid-100x100bp.png
./example-image-a5.tex
./example-image-c.eps
./example-image-9x16.eps
./example-image-a3.tex
./example-image-16x10.eps
./example-image-10x16.tex
./example-image-letter-numbered.pdf
./example-image-a.eps
./example-image.eps
./example-image-plain.tex
./example-image-16x9.pdf
./example-image-10x16.eps
```

Answer (score 7):

The files are part of the `mwe` package and can be found in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe
```

on a TeX Live distribution; they're found automatically, so knowing the location is not necessary for including them. It might be for copying one of them, but with a smart OS that's not required as well. Indeed, with `bash` syntax

```
cp $(kpsewhich example-image.png) .
```

will copy the file `example-image.png` to the current directory, taking it from the appropriate place in the TeX Live distribution.

Here's an annotated list; where `.{eps,jpg,pdf,png}` appears, it means that the image is available in all four formats.

```
% bordered rectangles with axes and diagonals and possibly a big letter in the middle
example-image.{eps,jpg,pdf,png}
example-image-a.{eps,jpg,pdf,png}
example-image-b.{eps,jpg,pdf,png}
example-image-c.{eps,jpg,pdf,png}

% images in the stated format showing it in the middle
example-image-1x1.{eps,jpg,pdf,png} 
example-image-4x3.{eps,jpg,pdf,png}
example-image-10x16.{eps,jpg,pdf,png}
example-image-16x10.{eps,jpg,pdf,png}
example-image-16x9.{eps,jpg,pdf,png}
example-image-9x16.{eps,jpg,pdf,png}

% sides in golden ratio
example-image-golden.pdf
example-image-golden-upright.pdf

% page sized images
example-image-a3.pdf
example-image-a3-landscape.pdf
example-image-a4.pdf
example-image-a4-numbered.pdf
example-image-a4-landscape.pdf
example-image-a5.pdf
example-image-a5-landscape.pdf
example-image-letter.pdf
example-image-letter-numbered.pdf
example-image-letter-landscape.pdf

% the basic rectangle with axes and diagonals used to build the other images
example-image-empty.pdf

% the basic rectangle with just the gray background
example-image-plain.pdf
```

Answer (score 5):

You can input any files that are in your TEXINPUTS.

In my texlive 2018 setup the images that are listed in the directories controlled by  ls-R files (`mktexlsr` or `texhash` etc) could be found with a command such as

```
  grep '[.]\(jpg\|png\|eps\)$' `kpsewhich --all ls-R`
```

which finds the following jpg, png and eps files

```
scite-context-visual.png
piicon.eps
oegatb-ex.png
still-expanding-1.png
still-expanding-10.png
still-expanding-2.png
still-expanding-3.png
still-expanding-4.png
still-expanding-5.png
still-expanding-6.png
still-expanding-7.png
still-expanding-8.png
still-expanding-9.png
hacker.jpg
mill.png
calibri-fontshop.png
ebook-metafun-1.png
ebook-metafun-2.png
ebook-pdf.png
ebook-xhtml.png
luatex-co-acceptablelowres.jpg
mtx-server-ctx-fonttest.png
tagged-001.png
tagged-002.png
tagged-003.png
tagged-004.png
tagged-005.png
tagged-006.png
tagged-007.png
tagged-008.png
tagged-009.png
tagged-010.png
tagged-011.png
hacker.png
m-1.png
m-2.png
mk-debug.png
mk-error.png
nodes-sun-pia-03149.jpg
nodes-sun-pia-03150.jpg
ma-cb-00.eps
ma-cb-01.png
ma-cb-03.png
ma-cb-04.png
ma-cb-07.png
ma-cb-08.png
ma-cb-12.png
ma-cb-13.png
ma-cb-15.png
ma-cb-16.png
ma-cb-18.png
ma-cb-19.png
ma-cb-20.png
ma-cb-21.png
ma-cb-22.png
ma-cb-23.png
ma-cb-24.png
ma-cb-25.png
ma-cb-26.png
still-acrobat-math.png
still-acrobat-text.png
still-math-stripe.png
still-sumatra-math.png
still-sumatra-text.png
swiglib-mkiv-gm-1.jpg
swiglib-mkiv-gm-1.png
bookmark.png
gardeninglion.jpg
header.png
autocompletion-command.jpg
autocompletion-word.jpg
bidi01.jpg
bidi02.jpg
bidi03.jpg
bidi04.jpg
bidi05.jpg
bidi06.jpg
bidi07.jpg
bidi08.jpg
bidi09.jpg
bidi10.jpg
calltip.jpg
dividingline.jpg
keywindow.jpg
nppexec1.jpg
nppexec2.jpg
nppexec3.jpg
rightclickmenu.jpg
scite-tools.jpg
style-configurator.jpg
tagsmenu.jpg
something.eps
transistor.eps
lscommnt.jpg
xhyper.jpg
clearsans.png
sample-massive.png
sample-phi4.png
sample-two-loop.png
sample-two-loop-annotated.png
sample-vertex.png
roadmap.eps
opentype.png
truetype.png
missaali-smallfont.png
missale-largefont.png
missale-normal.png
missale-preface.png
missale-tinyfont.png
pic-1.png
pic-2.png
word_features.png
Table.eps
didot-de.png
didot-fr.png
greek-contextual.png
opentype.png
serbian.png
spadmin.png
spadmin-add.png
stand-su.png
teubner.png
truetype.png
mh2scr0.png
wedn_fonttabelle.eps
wela_fonttabelle.eps
wesa_fonttabelle.eps
wesu_fonttabelle.eps
weva_fonttabelle.eps
myfigure.eps
teps.eps
tepsf.eps
teps.eps
tepsf.eps
miktex-languages.png
texlive-collection.png
pic1.eps
pic2.eps
dscf4684.jpg
pst_arc.eps
pst_arrow.eps
pst_axis.eps
pst_bezier.eps
pst_circle.eps
pst_color.eps
pst_curve.eps
pst_dot.eps
pst_fill.eps
pst_frame.eps
pst_grid.eps
pst_label.eps
pst_line.eps
pst_linestyle.eps
pst_origin.eps
pst_parabola.eps
pst_polygon.eps
pst_rput.eps
pst_uput.eps
universe.jpg
brave-gnu-world-logo.25.eps
brave-gnu-world-logo.25.jpg
brave-gnu-world-logo.eps
brave-gnu-world-logo.jpg
brave-gnu-world-logo-mask.jpg
file600.eps
auspost-1.eps
auspost-2.eps
aztec-1.eps
aztec-2.eps
aztec-3.eps
aztec-4.eps
aztec-5.eps
aztec-6.eps
bc412-1.eps
bc412-2.eps
bc412-3.eps
channelcode-1.eps
channelcode-2.eps
channelcode-3.eps
channelcode-4.eps
codabar-1.eps
codablockf-1.eps
codablockf-2.eps
codablockf-3.eps
code11-1.eps
code128-1.eps
code16k-1.eps
code16k-2.eps
code16k-3.eps
code25-1.eps
code25-2.eps
code32-1.eps
code39-1.eps
code39-2.eps
code39-3.eps
code39ext-1.eps
code39ext-2.eps
code49-1.eps
code49-2.eps
code49-3.eps
code93-1.eps
code93-2.eps
code93ext-1.eps
code93ext-2.eps
codeone-1.eps
codeone-2.eps
codeone-3.eps
codeone-4.eps
daft-1.eps
databarexpanded-1.eps
databarexpandedcomposite-1.eps
databarexpandedstacked-1.eps
databarexpandedstackedcomposite-1.eps
databarlimited-1.eps
databarlimitedcomposite-1.eps
databaromni-1.eps
databaromnicomposite-1.eps
databarstacked-1.eps
databarstackedcomposite-1.eps
databarstackedomni-1.eps
databarstackedomnicomposite-1.eps
databartruncated-1.eps
databartruncatedcomposite-1.eps
datamatrix-1.eps
datamatrix-2.eps
datamatrix-3.eps
ean128-1.eps
ean128-2.eps
ean128composite-1.eps
ean128composite-2.eps
ean13-1.eps
ean13-2.eps
ean13composite-1.eps
ean14-1.eps
ean2-1.eps
ean5-1.eps
ean8-1.eps
ean8-2.eps
ean8composite-1.eps
fima-1.eps
fimb-1.eps
fimc-1.eps
fimd-1.eps
flattermarken-1.eps
gs1composite-1.eps
gs1composite-2.eps
gs1composite-3.eps
gs1datamatrix-1.eps
gs1qrcode-1.eps
gs1qrcode-2.eps
hanxin-1.eps
hibccodablockf-1.eps
hibccode128-1.eps
hibccode39-1.eps
hibcdatamatrix-1.eps
hibcmicropdf417-1.eps
hibcpdf417-1.eps
hibcqrcode-1.eps
identcode-1.eps
isbn-1.eps
isbn-2.eps
isbn-3.eps
isbn-4.eps
ismn-1.eps
ismn-2.eps
ismn-3.eps
issn-1.eps
issn-2.eps
itf-1.eps
itf-14-1.eps
itf-2.eps
japanpost-1.eps
kix-1.eps
leitcode-1.eps
maxicode-1.eps
maxicode-2.eps
maxicode-3.eps
maxicode-4.eps
micropdf417-1.eps
micropdf417-2.eps
msi-1.eps
msi-2.eps
msi-3.eps
onecode-1.eps
optborder.eps
optcolorcmyk.eps
optcolorrgb.eps
optguardpos.eps
optguardsize.eps
optheight.eps
optincludecheck.eps
optincludecheckintext.eps
optincludetext.eps
optinkspread.eps
optparse.eps
optparsefnc.eps
optraw.eps
opttextfont.eps
optwidth.eps
pdf417-1.eps
pdf417-2.eps
pdf417-3.eps
pdf417-4.eps
pdf417-5.eps
pharmacode-1.eps
pharmacode2-1.eps
planet-1.eps
plessey-1.eps
plessey-2.eps
plessey-3.eps
posicode-1.eps
posicode-2.eps
posicode-3.eps
posicode-4.eps
posicode-5.eps
posicode-6.eps
postnet-1.eps
pzn-1.eps
pzn-2.eps
qrcode-1.eps
qrcode-2.eps
qrcode-5.eps
raw-1.eps
resize1.eps
resize2.eps
resize3.eps
rm4scc-1.eps
sscc18-1.eps
telepen-1.eps
telepen-2.eps
telepen-3.eps
telepen-4.eps
telepen-5.eps
upca-1.eps
upca-2.eps
upcacomposite-1.eps
upce-1.eps
upce-2.eps
upcecomposite-1.eps
spirale.eps
xa.eps
xb.eps
xc.eps
pst-plot-doc.eps
flowers.eps
tiger.eps
olympic.eps
shell.eps
kepler.eps
parrot.eps
tiger.eps
cercle-chromatique.eps
spirales-hsb.eps
circ.eps
circmag.eps
fountain.eps
gdansk.eps
screen.eps
kol-cmyk.eps
amsthm1.png
amsthm2.png
BAhhline.png
blk1.png
blk2.png
blk3.png
blk4.png
blk5.png
blk6.png
blk7.png
blk8.png
blk9.png
color.png
cute1.png
dotseqn.png
dropp1.png
easyeqn1.png
easyeqn10.png
easyeqn11.png
easyeqn12.png
easyeqn13.png
easyeqn14.png
easyeqn15.png
easyeqn16.png
easyeqn17.png
easyeqn3.png
easyeqn4.png
easyeqn6.png
easyeqn8.png
easyeqn9.png
fnpara.png
footmisc1.png
footmisc2.png
geom1.png
geom2.png
manyfoot1.png
multfoot1.png
multfoot2.png
rotbox.png
sublabel.png
undertilde-1.png
Xy-logo.png
grafico.eps
abntex2-modelo-livro-bandeirinha.jpg
abntex2-modelo-livro-pintassilgo.jpg
abntex2-modelo-livro-saira-amarela.jpg
cats.png
flies.eps
fly.eps
map.png
mouse.eps
rosette.eps
sigchi-logo.png
body.eps
header-logo-2006.eps
mosaic.jpg
adigraph-large.png
example_0.jpg
example_1.jpg
example_2.jpg
example_3.jpg
Thumbnail.jpg
vitruvian.jpg
figure_magnet.eps
aiaalgo.eps
smpfig.eps
smpfig.eps
smpfig.eps
180px-Gustave_Moreau_007.jpg
240px-Mort_du_fossoyeur.jpg
The_Wounded_Angel_-_Hugo_Simberg.jpg
Color2Gray.eps
gamuts.eps
rgb-cmyk.eps
spectrum.eps
seraphin-lampion.jpg
Dolor.jpg
Ipsum.jpg
Lorem.jpg
Sit.jpg
example.eps
stmlogo.jpg
diag.eps
diagleg.eps
tddiag.eps
beamerexample-lecture-pic1.jpg
beamerexample-lecture-pic2.jpg
beamerexample-lecture-pic3.jpg
beamerexample-lecture-pic4.jpg
beamerexample-lecture-pic5.jpg
beamerexample-lecture-pic6.jpg
colours.png
readme.jpg
Hannover-owl-1.png
Hannover-owl-2.png
Hannover-owl-1.png
Hannover-owl-2.png
metropolis-owl-1.png
metropolis-owl-2.png
metropolis-owl-1.png
metropolis-owl-2.png
Pittsburgh-owl-1.png
Pittsburgh-owl-2.png
Pittsburgh-owl-1.png
Pittsburgh-owl-2.png
ccby.png
dahut.jpg
img_5630.jpg
bluesimplex.png
FS-img1.png
FS-img2.png
FS-img3.png
LogoTop.png
demo-appendix.jpg
demo-focus.jpg
demo-references.jpg
demo-sectionpage.jpg
demo-titlepage.jpg
demo-titlepage-color.jpg
demo-typeset.jpg
propagating-elevation.eps
propagating-wave-height-x.eps
propagating-wave-length-x.eps
propagating-wave-period.eps
standing-elevation.eps
standing-wave-height-x.eps
standing-wave-length-x.eps
standing-wave-period.eps
automato1.jpg
automato2.jpg
automato3.jpg
automato4.jpg
automato5.jpg
ufpellogo.jpg
plato-aristotle.jpg
01b.png
02b.png
bild_ganz.eps
bild_mitte.eps
bild_oben.eps
bild_oben_unten.eps
bild_umflossen.eps
bild_unten.eps
bild_zu_lang.eps
bild_zu_lang2.eps
bild4c.png
times-ja2.png
times-nein2.png
egaligngb7714-2015.png
egaligngb7714-2015ay.png
eggbnamefmt.png
ligne_qui_ondule_sur_la_gauche.eps
bg.jpg
cards.png
dice.png
A319neo.jpg
test_10_simple_2x2_with_parbreak.png
test_20_thead_tfoot.png
test_30_tbreak.png
test_40_span.png
example_1.jpg
example_2.jpg
example_3.jpg
example_4.jpg
eps_demo.eps
icmphome.eps
graph18.eps
graph18.jpg
graph18.png
colorspaceshade.png
gnuplot42.eps
xfig325.eps
lightbulb.eps
fft_plot2.png
fft_plot2.png
fft_plot2.png
fft_plot2.png
fft_plot2.png
fft_plot2.png
fft_plot2.png
fft_plot2.png
fft_plot2.png
fft_plot2.png
coin.jpg
lion.png
penguin.jpg
MiKTeX-Basic.png
MiKTeX-Complete.png
TeXShopPNG.png
acrobat.png
backtic.png
cmdprom.png
cmdprom1.png
cmdprom2.png
cmdprom3.png
cmdprom4.png
cmdprom5.png
cmdprom6.png
cmdprom7.png
dinglist.png
dirviewer1.png
dirviewer2.png
dirviewer3.png
dirviewer4.png
draftimage.png
errormessage.png
exsamp.png
incgraph.png
incgraph2.png
maths.png
miktex1.png
newdoc-1.png
newdoc-2.png
notepad1.png
notepad2.png
reflbox.png
resizbox.png
rotbox.png
scalbox.png
terminal.png
terminal1.png
terminal10.png
terminal11.png
terminal2.png
terminal3.png
terminal4.png
terminal5.png
terminal6.png
terminal7.png
terminal8.png
terminal9.png
terminal-texdoc.png
texworks1.png
texworks2.png
texworks3.png
texworks4.png
texworks5.png
texworks6.png
texworks7.png
texworks8.png
texworks9.png
texworks-latexmk.png
texworks-preferences.png
texworks-toolconfig1.png
texworks-toolconfig2.png
texworks-toolconfig3.png
texworks-toolconfig4.png
yap1.png
arara-installer.png
bibertool.png
doibutton.png
generatekey.png
jabref1.png
jabref10.png
jabref10-thumbnail.png
jabref11.png
jabref12.png
jabref12-thumbnail.png
jabref1-thumbnail.png
jabref2.png
jabref3.png
jabref3-thumbnail.png
jabref4.png
jabref4-thumbnail.png
jabref5.png
jabref5-thumbnail.png
jabref6.png
jabref6-thumbnail.png
jabref7.png
jabref7-thumbnail.png
jabref8.png
jabref8-thumbnail.png
jabref9.png
jabref9-thumbnail.png
jabref-dataprop.png
jabref-dataprop-thumbnail.png
jabref-pref.png
jabref-pref-thumbnail.png
jabref-textimport1.png
jabref-textimport1-thumbnail.png
jabref-textimport2.png
jabref-textimport2-thumbnail.png
jabref-textimport3.png
jabref-textimport3-thumbnail.png
texworks-addbutton.png
texworks-arara.png
texworks-arara2.png
texworks-bibtex.png
texworks-latexmk.png
texworks-latexmkbibtex.png
texworks-makeglossaries.png
texworks-pdflatex.png
texworks-pref.png
texworks-texindy.png
fig.eps
facsimile.eps
sec-facsimile.eps
facsimile.eps
sec-facsimile.eps
fig.eps
fig.eps
facsimile.eps
sec-facsimile.eps
facsimile.eps
sec-facsimile.eps
fig.eps
athena.jpg
portrait.eps
B.eps
test-ill.png
eltecimerszines.eps
eltecimerszines.jpg
emarks-fingerprint.png
Fingerprint.jpg
dice.eps
Ball.eps
box1.eps
box2.eps
cm.eps
Construction.eps
danger.eps
graphic.eps
mass.eps
origin.eps
pale.eps
pend.eps
pretzel.eps
rdanger.eps
rosette.eps
square.eps
Warning.eps
wide.eps
image.eps
image2.eps
nola.eps
red_corps_castle2.eps
example.eps
ET_logo.jpg
HTL.png
HTL-Allgemein.jpg
spiral.eps
houses.eps
pexaminipage.eps
shorthyp_t1xtts.eps
1.jpg
2.jpg
blank.jpg
blue.png
frame.png
green.png
item.png
orange.png
point.png
cite.png
antenne.png
batterie.png
biellettes.png
bouton.png
moteur.png
pedalier.png
pignons.png
recepteur.png
roue.png
servomoteur.png
smiley.eps
epsfig.eps
latex-first.png
latex-second-a.png
latex-second-b.png
latex-second-c.png
vitruvian.jpg
im01.eps
im02.eps
im03.eps
im04.eps
im05.eps
im06.eps
im0.eps
im1.eps
im10.eps
im11.eps
im12.eps
im13.eps
im14.eps
im15.eps
im16.eps
im2.eps
im3.eps
im4.eps
im5.eps
im6.eps
im7.eps
im8.eps
im9.eps
an3.png
im1.png
im10.png
im11.png
im12.png
im13.png
im14.png
im15.png
im16.png
im17.png
im18.png
im19.png
im2.png
im20.png
im21.png
im22.png
im23.png
im24.png
im25.png
im26.png
im27.png
im28.png
im29.png
im3.png
im30.png
im31.png
im32.png
im33.png
im34.png
im35.png
im36.png
im37.png
im38.png
im39.png
im4.png
im40.png
im41.png
im42.png
im43.png
im44.png
im45.png
im46.png
im5.png
im6.png
im7.png
im8.png
im9.png
egg.eps
egg.png
sheep.eps
sheep.png
Bjarne.eps
Bjarnes.eps
Bjornstrup.eps
BjornstrupS.eps
Conny.eps
Connys.eps
Glenn.eps
Glenns.eps
Lenny.eps
Lennys.eps
Rejne.eps
Rejnes.eps
Sonny.eps
Sonnys.eps
cat.eps
bg_cle_tile.eps
grandcanyon.eps
IndianBlanket.eps
news_bgr.eps
Wood-Brown.eps
band02.png
band08.png
demo.eps
denis.png
cola-public-domain-photo-p.jpg
screenshot-clean.png
screenshot-dirty.png
screenshot-clean.png
screenshot-dirty.png
ball-bearing-1.png
ball-bearing-2.png
cola-public-domain-photo-p.jpg
ellipse-parameters-2.png
freehand-export-screen-setup.png
ibm-360-color.jpg
inkscape-pdf-save-screenhot.png
overhang-mounting.png
photoshop-eps-screen.png
screenshot-clean.png
screenshot-dirty.png
straddle-mounting.png
techniccenter-profile-dvi-26.png
techniccenter-profile-dvips-26.png
yap-inverse-search-settings.png
wct1.eps
wct10.eps
wct5.eps
zfb.eps
bthesistitle.eps
golfer.eps
hitlogo.eps
Bruennhilde.eps
Bruennhilde.jpg
Gccs.eps
Gccs.jpg
signat.eps
signat.jpg
bateaux.jpg
rose.png
example1.eps
example2.eps
example3.eps
example4.eps
example5.eps
example6.eps
example7.eps
graph.eps
icon_draft.eps
ids.eps
logfile.eps
openmsg_six.eps
openmsg_sixinbrowser.eps
paperclip.eps
pushpin.eps
tag.eps
vk.eps
tux.eps
pic001.jpg
pic002.jpg
pic003.jpg
pic004.jpg
pic005.jpg
pic006.jpg
pic007.jpg
pic008.jpg
pic009.jpg
pic010.jpg
pic011.jpg
pic012.jpg
pic013.jpg
pic014.jpg
pic015.jpg
pic016.jpg
pic017.jpg
pic018.jpg
pic019.jpg
pic020.jpg
pic021.jpg
pic022.jpg
bild.eps
exaimage-0001.png
exaimage-0037.png
exaimage-0123.png
example.jpg
example.jpg
buttonappearance.eps
checkclear.eps
checksubmit.eps
exerques1.eps
exerques10.eps
exerques11.eps
exerques12.eps
exerques13.eps
exerques14.eps
exerques15.eps
exerques16.eps
exerques17.eps
exerques18.eps
exerques19.eps
exerques2.eps
exerques20.eps
exerques3.eps
exerques4.eps
exerques5.eps
exerques6.eps
exerques7.eps
exerques8.eps
exerques9.eps
fieldclear.eps
fieldsubmit.eps
ndex.eps
next.eps
pageonecheckfive.eps
pageonecheckfour.eps
pageonecheckone.eps
pageonecheckthree.eps
pageonechecktwo.eps
pageonefieldfive.eps
pageonefieldfour.eps
pageonefieldone.eps
pageonefieldthree.eps
pageonefieldtwo.eps
pageonepopupfive.eps
pageonepopupfour.eps
pageonepopupone.eps
pageonepopupthree.eps
pageonepopuptwo.eps
pageoneradiofive.eps
pageoneradiofour.eps
pageoneradioone.eps
pageoneradiothree.eps
pageoneradiotwo.eps
pagethreecheckfive.eps
pagethreecheckfour.eps
pagethreecheckone.eps
pagethreecheckthree.eps
pagethreechecktwo.eps
pagethreefieldfive.eps
pagethreefieldfour.eps
pagethreefieldone.eps
pagethreefieldthree.eps
pagethreefieldtwo.eps
pagethreepopupfive.eps
pagethreepopupfour.eps
pagethreepopupone.eps
pagethreepopupthree.eps
pagethreepopuptwo.eps
pagethreeradiofive.eps
pagethreeradiofour.eps
pagethreeradioone.eps
pagethreeradiothree.eps
pagethreeradiotwo.eps
pagetwocheckfive.eps
pagetwocheckfour.eps
pagetwocheckone.eps
pagetwocheckthree.eps
pagetwochecktwo.eps
pagetwofieldfive.eps
pagetwofieldfour.eps
pagetwofieldone.eps
pagetwofieldthree.eps
pagetwofieldtwo.eps
pagetwopopupfive.eps
pagetwopopupfour.eps
pagetwopopupone.eps
pagetwopopupthree.eps
pagetwopopuptwo.eps
pagetworadiofive.eps
pagetworadiofour.eps
pagetworadioone.eps
pagetworadiothree.eps
pagetworadiotwo.eps
popupclear.eps
popupsubmit.eps
prev.eps
radioclear.eps
radiosubmit.eps
return.eps
rightcheckcorrect.eps
rightfieldcorrect.eps
rightpopupcorrect.eps
rightradiocorrect.eps
wrongcheckcorrect.eps
wrongfieldcorrect.eps
wrongpopupcorrect.eps
wrongradiocorrect.eps
jacow2017.jpg
bookLogo.png
bookLogo-gray.png
circle.jpg
circle-gray.png
nodes.png
nodes-gray.png
square.png
square-gray.png
dummy.eps
kdg_color.eps
pi-orchid.jpg
mouse.eps
lion.png
jeyre.jpg
histkotex.jpg
list.eps
list.png
inkscape.png
inkscape-tb.png
tbx.eps
inkscape.png
inkscape-tb.png
tbx.eps
diagram-crop.eps
fullscreen.eps
fullscreen.png
sample-crop.eps
typo-degraded.eps
typo-degraded.png
campus3.png
Ross-Siegel.png
Leslie_Lamport.jpg
B.eps
logo.png
menno-a.png
phys332-1.eps
phys332-2.eps
colorcir.eps
colorcir.eps
tac2dim.eps
phys332-1.eps
phys332-2.eps
djd17novL.eps
djd17novR.eps
djdpoems1.eps
djdpoems2.eps
djdpoems3.eps
djdpoems4.eps
egarab.eps
egarabpar.eps
ledarden.eps
ledbraonain.eps
ledeasy.eps
ledekker.eps
ledfeat.eps
ledioc.eps
ledmixed.eps
villon.eps
picture.png
compact.png
Fig1.png
Fig2.png
Fig3a.png
Fig3b.png
Fig4.png
logbox.png
qrcode.png
instructions-differential.eps
triangle.eps
basem3-1.eps
basem3-2.eps
basem3-3.eps
basem3-4.eps
cube.eps
products.eps
mcmthesis-aaa.eps
ctan-lion.png
cafe-logo.png
Recompilation_decision.eps
772px-1st_Marine_Division_insignia.png
lamed3.png
example.eps
example.png
picture.eps
picture.jpg
mailto.png
logo-1.png
navy-logo-102.png
draft.eps
lvb.eps
palm.eps
wine.eps
atom.jpg
100euroie.png
100euroit.png
1eurogr.jpg
recycled.png
vitruvian.jpg
fig_NoiseData_ClosedLine.eps
fig_NoiseData_OpenLine.eps
samplefigure.eps
ireland.jpg
clouds.jpg
rain.jpg
sun.jpg
attention.png
coeur.png
prerequis.png
warning-perso.png
photo.png
simbin.eps
pdfmarginparexample.png
ar1.png
ar2.png
ar3.png
tex.png
JWGU-Logo.png
marble.png
armtex-meta.png
math-assign5.png
TL-POL-meta.png
TL-RU-LICRs.png
TL-RU-metadata.png
TL-RU-toc.png
usage-meta.png
baseline.png
ornaments.png
TeX_box.png
logo.png
logo.png
cactus.eps
FUbib.eps
FULogo.eps
FULogo_RGB.eps
FUseal.eps
silberlaube2.eps
introFonts.png
beamernavbar.png
FUbib.jpg
FULogo.png
FULuft.jpg
geo.jpg
ligaturen.png
multimedia.jpg
multimedia.png
silberlaube.jpg
silberlaube2.jpg
TU.jpg
FUbib.eps
fuBIB10.eps
FULogo.eps
FULogo_RGB.eps
FULogo2.eps
FULogoRGB.eps
logofbbw.eps
silberlaube.eps
silberlaube2.eps
wieesgeht.eps
zedat2.eps
tex.png
beamernavbar.png
grating.png
ligaturen.png
multimedia.jpg
transition1.png
TU.jpg
clemson.png
logo-clemson.png
logofbbw.eps
moviePD.png
pawmkorange.png
pawmkpurple.png
pawtraceorange.png
pawtracep.png
wieesgeht.eps
zedat2.eps
tex.png
prosper.png
prosper-template.jpg
example.eps
testfig.eps
tux.jpg
b6of1.eps
b6of2.eps
b6of3.eps
b6of4.eps
BZ10.eps
BZ6.eps
BZ7.eps
BZ8.eps
BZ9.eps
vecb1.eps
vecb2.eps
vecb3.eps
vecb4.eps
vecb5.eps
vecb6.eps
blueshade.png
QT.png
Curried_butternut_squash_soup.jpg
Curried_chicken_and_rice.jpg
French_dip.jpg
Grilled_chicken_with_capers.jpg
Hawaiian_burgers.jpg
Italian_calzones.jpg
Pumpkin_pie_soup.jpg
example.jpg
fig_1.eps
fig_2.eps
fig_1.eps
fig_2.eps
vid_1a.eps
vid_1b.eps
fig_1.eps
fig_2.eps
vitruvian.jpg
sageep_graphic2009.jpg
blocks1.eps
blocks1a.eps
blocks1mx.eps
blocks1vx.eps
blocks2.eps
blocks2mx.eps
blocks3.eps
blocks3mx.eps
blocks3op.eps
blocks3openvx.eps
blocks3rec.eps
blocks3vx.eps
blocksopen3a.eps
blocksopen3vx.eps
blocksopen3vy.eps
000074Bpatspec.png
000074Bzones.jpg
000175Bpatspec.png
000175Bzones.jpg
002000AApatspec.png
002000AAzones.jpg
lambda2.jpg
orig.jpg
logotex.eps
tiger.eps
back-cover.png
doctor.png
engineering.png
front-cover.jpg
master.png
seu-badge-logo.eps
seu-color-logo.png
seu-text-logo.eps
seu-text-logo.png
back-cover.png
doctor.png
engineering.png
front-cover.jpg
lxfbook.jpg
master.png
seu_logo.jpg
seu-badge-logo.eps
seu-color-logo.png
seu-text-logo.eps
seu-text-logo.png
fig1.eps
fig2.eps
mcr3b.eps
capture.eps
logo.jpg
din8.eps
Basilica_5.png
lichtspiel.jpg
vmlinux.eps
vmlinux.png
Logo.jpg
quetta.eps
data.png
file_extensions.png
orbital_mechanics.png
picard_yes.jpg
tumblr_lrvyd1GuNe1r3aueno1_400.jpg
LogoFH.eps
LogoFH.png
pdf_normal.eps
tsinghua.eps
thu-fig-logo.eps
thu-lib-logo.eps
thu-text-logo.eps
thu-whole-logo.eps
logo.png
dimline1.png
dimline2.png
dimline3.png
shell_escape.jpg
plane.png
example.png
...
```

full list is 2638 files and exceeds the character limit of posts to this site.

Comment: actually some of these may be in the doc tree but looking at the ls-r file would show that (grep only shows one line so the directory isn't shown in these results)